# Alternative for MSE

Tags: wcf, mse

I found MSE(Managed Service Engine) very difficult and slow to use.Microsoft is no longer putting any effort into MSE. It was never a supported project anyways.What is the best alternative of MSE?

Comment: Voting to close as not constructive, especially since the answer is right on the [Managed Services Engine](http://servicesengine.codeplex.com/) home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can refer you to [LinkSpan](http://linkspan.therightapi.com/Welcome) and/or [Sentient](http://www.nevatech.com/).  To be honest, I found out about them after I went to the [MSE page on codeplex](http://servicesengine.codeplex.com/).

We went with LinkSpan because it was by the original authors of MSE.

Comment: Thanks Dan,I will research your advices.

Answer (score 0):

LinkSpan is a cloud hosted solution targeted at REST APIs. Nevatech's Sentinet is a full energize-level implementation of the services virtualization concept with the focus on both SOAP and REST, and for on-premises and cloud environments. Microsoft MSE team praised Sentinet as MSE successor, http://www.prweb.com/releases/2012/5/prweb9483718.htm.